# ¿se puede añadir el contenido de una variable a un array en C?

Tags: c

Intente añadir la variable al arreglo como cuando se declaracon datos dentro pero parece ser que no se ejecuta correctamente

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
  float a,b;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("Kilometraje: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("Litros de gasolina: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    float rendimiento=b/a;
    float datos[]={rendimiento};//aqui intente añadir la variable como si se añadiera un dato al declarar el arreglo
    printf("\n%f \n\n",datos[i]);
  }
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar solo esta parte cada vez que introduzco los dos datos al principio se hace bien la división y después no.

Lo que tengo que hacer es pedir dos datos (`a` y `b`) dividirlos y añadir el resultado al arreglo para posteriormente dividirlos entre el numero de datos (promedio).

Answer (score 0):

Creía que no era posible crear arreglos de esa manera, pero acabo de [probarlo](https://tio.run/##bY9dTsMwEITfc4pRUFGrGtIC5S8NF4AbkD5sHKcscmywHV6qHoozcLDgpq1UJF5Wmv1mtTPyYi1l35@xkbqrFZY@1Gwv354SgE1AS2zGk01UjbYUQKLKk52ybrzjXMxyXs7jmE4HG/DhImjG6TNr26rg6F09Ip3kA/SSTGSjJhXn1WF3PHjh4KxHTLEmbzUb@v@ODrt9IqdMzS0rE2xRZXSKagrWv65QbE5MAlcC1wI3AguBW4E7gXuBB4H5DNs8y@iz4133aFagn2@q2UETvsgxVVpB2tbCM/wRK0fozPAOpGMBqcmRg9Ig59Ra2z89SzNqUJrSpGKfkFdDo22y7ftFsvgF) y aparentemente es válido crear un arreglo mediante variables.

Sospecho que solo se puede lograr en compiladores que soportan [VLA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) (arreglos de tamaño variable) por lo que deberías evitarlo si pretendes crear un programa portable.

Al grano: la división siempre ocurre correctamente. Lo que sucede es que arreglo en todas las ocasiones tiene un solo elemento, sin embargo `i` toma valores fuera del rango (0 es la única posición válida).

Con esta pequeña corrección bastará:

```
printf("\n%f \n\n", datos[0]);
```

---

Por otro lado, ¿para qué quieres tener siempre un arreglo de un solo elemento? Mejor usa una variable normal.

O quizá lo que en realidad quieres es leer los valores, ponerlos en el arreglo y luego procesarlos. Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float a, b;
    float kilometraje[10], gasolina[10];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("Kilometraje: ");
        scanf("%f", &kilometraje[i]);
        printf("Litros de gasolina: ");
        scanf("%f", &gasolina[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        float rendimiento = kilometraje [i] / gasolina[i];
        printf("\n%f \n\n", rendimiento);
    }
}
```